# Window var in javascript not returning from ajax without pause

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables

So I have a piece of code defines the name of a kmz file I need to drop in Google Maps. I define it at the top of the script as a window var with a default value

```
 window.kmz="Delaware_River_Basin.kmz"
```

Now I run some ajax and return what the window kmz should really be. This always is returning the correct answer. Nothing wrong with this script.

```
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   dataType:'json',
       url:'/includes/kmz.php',
       data:{id:window.whichID},
       success:function(data) {
         window.kmz=data[0];
      },
```

});

Later on down the page I now need to get this kmz file into maps

```
 var watersheds = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
     url:'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/map/'+window.kmz+'?a=2',
     suppressInfoWindows: true
 });
  watersheds.setMap(map);
```

The window.kmz in Mozilla always comes in correctly as the call from the ajax. In Explorer and other browsers the window.kmz is not the ajax call but always the default. The kicker here is if I alert box window.kmz prior to the watershed var being defined it will alert the default but then the actual ajax call works. It is like it needs a pause to find that ajax call! Why does Mozilla work with it but Explorer and Chrome gag? Chrome sometimes gags but Explorer is totally out.

Comment: Don't use `window.kmz` until you are certain that `success` handler has fired.

Comment: There's go guarantee as to when the ajax POST will finish. If you need to use data returned from it, the safest place to do that is in the success handler.

Comment: **A**jax is **Asynchronous**.

Comment: Every code requires `kmz` need to be located in `success` callback

Answer (score 0):

Every code requires `kmz` need to be located in `success` callback. Or if it is your server you can set cookies on the server side and you will be able to get `kmz` synchronously